# How to set a value for a variable in Robot framework test case?

Tags: selenium2, robotframework

Is there any option in Robot framework to set the value of a variable "TRUE" or "FALSE" depending upon a condition ?

I want to run a keyword only if a condition is TRUE, i.e. a keyword should run only if a particular ID exists in present screen.

Here is my test script -

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Test Setup  Open Browser  http://xyz.com  chrome
Test Teardown  Close All Browsers

*** Variables ***
${IdExist}  None

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
  Open Application and check page content

*** Keywords ***
Open application and check page content
  Maximize Browser Window
  Sleep  2s
  Click Element  id=Start
  Sleep  2s
  ${IdExist} = Page Should Contain Element  id=hamburger-icon
  Run Keyword if   "${IdExist}" == "PASS"  Click Button

Click Button
  Click Element  id=hamburger-icon
```

Is this a Correct way of writing a test script to set the value for a variable?

`${IdExist} = Page Should Contain Element  id=hamburger-icon`

I found this particular piece of code in a website ! 
But, while running the above test case, the value of the variable is not getting set as TRUE / PASS  value, even though the particular icon exists in present screen (The keyword `Click Button` is not at all triggering!)

Is there any other effective way to handle this particular scenario?

Am I missing something? Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is cumbersome, but there are a couple things you can do.

If you don't care about the message returned by the first keyword, you can use [Run keyword and return status](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Return%20Status). This is perhaps the easiest solution, since the keyword will return either `True` or `False`.

```
${status}=    Run keyword and return status
...    Page should contain element    id=hamburger-icon
Run keyword if  ${status}   Click button
```

If you want the status of a keyword and also what it returns, you can call [Run Keyword and Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error), which returns two values: "PASS" or "FAIL", and the return value or error message from the keyword. You can then use the "PASS" or "FAIL" result in your if statement.

```
${status}    ${result}=    Run keyword and ignore error
...    Page Should Contain Element  id=hamburger-icon
Run keyword if    "${status}" == "FAIL"
...    Click button
```